# c# program question

Tags: c#

if a textbox has 1 digit or a number that's larger than 31, the program will crash. how should I stop that?

so far, i have this code:

```
if (dd.Text.Length <= 1 || dd.Text > 31)
    return;
```

obviously, that's wrong... :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here. Are you parsing the day of month? In that case you can't check towards 31 since not all month have 31 days. Also comparing a string (I guess that Text is a string) towards the number 31 will not work as you expect.

Comment: What's the code that uses your textbox? And you're missing a ".Length" on the second part of your if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dd.Text > 31
```

The above code is comparing a string to an int.  You should try:

```
int val = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(dd.Text, out val))
{
   if (val > 31) return;
}
```

Comment: btw, you can don't initialize `val` to `0` - it will be done automatically by out-accepting method

Answer (score 3):

```
dd.Text > 31
```

This line wont work.  Try:

```
int.parse(dd.Text) > 31
```

Also if non numeric characters are entered it wont run, you might want to sanitise first.

Answer (score -1):

What is obvious that You don't think about that what are You doing.

First of all You must to understand what basic types are available in C# and for what re they.

For now You should read about String, and Integer. The You will understand why that code do not work.

If You want to verify, that a text value form a textBox is between two numbers, first of all it need to be number. So You need to cast it...

Then You can operate on it and compare.

```
String myText = textBox.Text;
int myValue  = -1;

if(Int32.tryPart(myText,myValue))    
 if(myValue > 31)
   return;
```

Comment: Why do You write the first letter in the word You with a capital by the way? Don't You know that's now how it's done? :P

Comment: The habit of spelling rules of my native language.